# Gitlab CI/CD test whether pm2 start gives errors

Tags: gitlab-ci, pm2, cicd

So I am trying to make a CI/CD pipeline for the first time as I have no experience with DevOps at all, and I want to add pm2 to it, so I can test whether it is able to successfully start the API without issues. This way, I can ensure that the API works when being deployed.

The one issue I have is if I do pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env development, how will the pipeline know whether this startup is successful or not?

This is currently the YAML file that I have:

```
image: node:10.19.0

services:
  - mongo:3.6.8
  - pm2:3.5.1

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm run lint
    - pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env development
```

Any ideas how you can test pm2 startup?

Thanks in advance!

## UPDATE #1:

The reason why I want to test pm2 startup is that pm2 has several "process.env" variables that are required in my API to be started.
Starting the API without those variables immediately gives errors, as it needs the variables to initialize the connection to other APIs.

So I don't know whether there is a workaround to be able to start the API without an issue?

Comment: I didn't understand what issue you facing with gitlab CI/CD.  How are u determining if pm2 runs successfully in your local machine.

If u only what to see the env variables and their values in before_script or in script u can use `printenv`

Comment: It's not about seeing the process env, it's about how do i start my node.js api to test whether it is able to startup without failing. I can't do node . because it errors immediately since it doesn't have the process.env variables so I thought to start it with pm2 but then like I mentioned it isn't able to detect the issues of the launched app.

Comment: I didn't understand which issue you are facing with GitLab CI/CD. However, it could be an authentication problem as I didn't find anything from your yml file. I write a blog post for deploying ci/cd with GitLab runner and pm2. Hopefully, this will help you to solve your problem. [Please check it out from this link](https://medium.com/@roomeyrahman/ci-cd-configuration-with-gitlab-runner-and-pm2-7d96bcd06ea9)